# emacs org-mode \label in html export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to export an org-mode file with labelled latex formulas inside it to HTML without having the `\label{eq:1}` in the output. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (assuming you are using org-ref https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref) which exports the ref link to html:

```
* equations in html

See ref:eq-1.



#+BEGIN_HTML
<div id="eq-1">
#+END_HTML
\begin{equation}
e^x = 4
\end{equation}
```

This exports to something like:

```
<div id="eq-1">
\begin{equation}
e^x = 4
\end{equation}

<p>
See <a href="#eq-1">eq-1</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to keep the org-file latex exportable.

Comment: that is still latex exportable. the HTML bit will not show up in latex, and in latex export, ref:eq-1 exports to \ref{eq-1} exactly like you need. I pushed a new addition to org-ref that even exports the label as <div id=label>

Comment: Thank you! At the moment I am using reftex. Do you think that I can do something similar with it? Do you think org-ref works better?

Comment: No, you have to configure the export behavior in org-mode, and reftex cannot help you with that.